# How to call webservice of localhost(from wamp or xampp server) in android?

Tags: android, web-services, xampp, localhost, wamp

I am getting response of webservice of live URL but if i am using URL of my local PC ,i.e localhost it 's stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have to use `IP-Address` instead of `localhost`. Something like:

```
http://10.0.2.2:8080/site/uri
```

For more information on read [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html) article.

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish your web Service at local server and then change the URL you are using in your app. 
For example, if your web service is in asmx then you need to publish it at IIS, while php web service need to publish at WAMP etc.